.Net Core Service Runs but Still Get Console Error 1053
I have created a .Net Core 8.0 application which should work either in console mode or as a Windows service. So I can lift and shift the core logic from another application I am using VB.Net.
My main code and builder look like this:
    Sub Main(args As String())
    Try
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "Main Program", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Dim oBuilder As IHostBuilder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(args)
        oBuilder.Build.Run
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "Main Program exits", EventLogEntryType.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Function CreateHostBuilder(args As String()) As IHostBuilder
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "CreateHostBuilder", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices(Sub(hostContext, services)
                                                                     services.AddHostedService(Of VideoConvertorService)()
                                                                 End Sub)
    End Function
End Class

My service implementation currently looks like this:
Public Class VideoConvertorService
    Implements IHostedService
    Private sModule As String = "VideoConvertorService"
    Private WithEvents oTimer As Timers.Timer = New Timers.Timer(60 * 1000)

    Public Function StartAsync(cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task Implements IHostedService.StartAsync
        Try
            EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "Service starting...", EventLogEntryType.Information)
            oTimer.Enabled = True
            EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "Service started", EventLogEntryType.Information)
            Return Task.CompletedTask
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogMessage(New ErrorDetail(LSError, ex.Message, "", sModule & "." & GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex))
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function StopAsync(cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task Implements IHostedService.StopAsync
        Try
            EventLog.WriteEntry(sService, "Service stopping...", EventLogEntryType.Information)
            Return Task.CompletedTask
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogMessage(New ErrorDetail(LSError, ex.Message, "", sModule & "." & GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex))
        End Try
    End Function

This "works" in the sense that it works exactly as expected in the console, but it also runs through to the "Service Started" line in StartAsync() when I run it as a service. Therefore all of the usual issues around framework versions, permissions etc. are not at issue here. However I am still getting a 1053 error from the service console. If I look into the event log there are all my diagnostic messages as I'd expect, and no other exception messages.
As you can see the StartAsync() routine does no work apart from start the service, so there's definitely no timeout issue either.
It looks like I need to do something as well as the "Return Task.CompletedTask" to get the console to recognise that the service is running OK, but I don't know what.
Thanks
